# Append generated json tree

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to ask you for help. I have a Device object

```
public class Device {
    public String name;
    public String deviceId;

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomResourceSerializer.class)
    public Map<String, Map<String, Object>> customResources;
}
```

My goal is to "extract" this map directly to Device Object. Firstly I used `@JsonAnyGetter` which worked well and Map was nested under field String of first map directly under Device object.

But I need more complex logic and I have two problems which I don't know how to solve.

1. Key of first map is for example `"configuration/inputOne"`. With `@JsonAnyGetter` the example output is `{ "configuration/inputOne": { "rate":23 } }`

What I need is nested structure based on delimiter, so

```
{ "configuration": { "inputOne": { "rate":23 } } }
```

This I was almost able to do easily with custom JsonSerializer

```
jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
foreach(splited key)
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart(resourceUriItem);
foreach(value)
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField(k, v);
foreach(splitted key)
    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
```

But final object looks like

```
{ "customResource": {"configuration": { "inputOne": { "rate":23 } } } }
```

CustomResource field is from Device object and I don't know how to get rid of it. As with JsonAnyGetter. That's the first problem.

2. As you see, I am splitting the key of the map to have more nested strucutre, so from the "configuration/inputOne" to `{ configuration { inputOne { .. } }`. But the map customResources can have of course multiple items, so for example:

   - `"configuration/inputOne"`
   - `"configuration/inputTwo"`
   - `"configuration"`

Now you probably see where is the problem. As I am iterating over keys and I am creating nested structure, I will override it. So for example, firstly I will create object configuration, then inputOne and fill it with fields. Closing objects. Then second item in map, creating configuration object and inputTwo object. But with creation of configuration, I will delete the one previously created with inputOne.

Do you have any proposal how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your map into a type of a tree by splitting on the `/` and creating a parent child relationship on the split items.

Using the following class as a tree element / node.

```
class TreeElement {
    private String key;
    private Object value;

    private List<TreeElement> children;

    public TreeElement(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    // getters and setters here

    public void addChild(TreeElement child) {
        if (this.children == null) {
            this.children = new ArrayList<TreeElement>();
        }

        this.children.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;

        result = prime * result + ((key == null) ? 0 : key.hashCode());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        TreeElement other = (TreeElement) obj;
        if (key == null) {
            if (other.key != null)
                return false;

        } else if (!key.equalsIgnoreCase(other.key))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TreeElement [key=" + key + ", value=" + value + ", children=" + children + "]";
    }
}
```

And the following test code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // create the config1, config2, etc.. here

            Device device1 = new Device();

            device1.customResources = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>();
            device1.customResources.put("configuration/inputOne", config1);
            device1.customResources.put("configuration/inputTwo", config2);
            device1.customResources.put("configuration", config3);
            device1.customResources.put("configuration", duplicateConfig3);
            device1.customResources.put("otherConfig", otherConfig);
            device1.customResources.put("thirdConfig1", thirdConfig1);
            device1.customResources.put("thirdConfig1/inputOne", thirdConfig2);
            device1.customResources.put("thirdConfig1/inputOne", duplicateThirdConfig2);

            List<TreeElement> elements = new ArrayList<TreeElement>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : device1.customResources.entrySet()) {
                TreeElement element = generateElement(null, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

                elements.add(element);
            }

            List<TreeElement> joinedElements = joinElements(elements);

            for (TreeElement e : joinedElements) {
                System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue());

                if (e.getChildren() != null) {
                    for (TreeElement c : e.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println("\t" + c.getKey() + " - " + c.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This method generates a TreeElement from a Map> variable.

```
    private static TreeElement generateElement(TreeElement parent, String item, Map<String, Object> value) {
        try {
            List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(item.split("/")));

            TreeElement child = new TreeElement(tokens.get(0));

            boolean parentWasNull = false;

            if (parent == null) {
                parent = child;
                parentWasNull = true;
            }

            if (tokens.size() > 1) {
                if (parentWasNull == false) {
                    parent.addChild(child);
                }

                tokens.remove(0);

                generateElement(child, StringUtils.join(tokens, "/"), value);
            } else {
                child.setValue(value);

                if (parentWasNull == false) {
                    parent.addChild(child);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return parent;
    }
```

This method joins common TreeElement objects into one parent and multiple children.

```
    private static List<TreeElement> joinElements(List<TreeElement> elements) {
        List<TreeElement> joinedElements = new ArrayList<TreeElement>();

        for (TreeElement element : elements) {
            if (joinedElements.contains(element) == true) {
                // joined elment does not have children
                if (joinedElements.get(joinedElements.indexOf(element)).getChildren() == null) {
                    joinedElements.get(joinedElements.indexOf(element)).setChildren(element.getChildren());
                } else {
                    //joined element has children and the current element also has children
                    if (element.getChildren() != null) {
                        joinedElements.get(joinedElements.indexOf(element)).getChildren().addAll(element.getChildren());
                    }
                }

                /*
                 * set the value of joined element to the value of the current element; will overwrite 
                 * any existing value if duplicates exist
                 */
                if (element.getValue() != null) {
                    joinedElements.get(joinedElements.indexOf(element)).setValue(element.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                joinedElements.add(element);
            }
        }

        return joinedElements;
    }
```

I'm not sure how efficient this code is, but you get the below output which you can traverse in your custom serializer to print to JSON.

```
thirdConfig1 - {rate=30}
    inputOne - {rate=3020}
configuration - {rate=1200}
    inputOne - {rate=23}
    inputTwo - {rate=50}
otherConfig - {rate=10}
```